# Classes and self in python: instance and class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instance

I'm a novice Python programmer utterly confused by OOP and the need for `self` in classes. I've read the many SO posts, blogs* etc that attempt to demystify it, but could use some help on this particular scenario.

I am basing the below scenarios off the [Python2 tutorial on Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables). I'll lead with my examples, followed by explicit questions beneath.

First, I'll directly set `tricks`, and then use the `add_trick` method:

```
class Dog:

    tricks = []      

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks.append(trick)

    def print_self_tricks(self):
        print(self.tricks)

a = Dog('spencer')
b = Dog('rex')

a.tricks = ['foo'] # How is this even possible? Where did I define self.tricks? 

a.print_self_tricks()
['foo']    # Ok, the below results make sense
b.print_self_tricks()
[]
a.tricks
['foo']
b.tricks
[]

a.add_trick('jump')

a.print_self_tricks()
['foo', 'jump']
b.print_self_tricks()
[]          # Great, as expected
a.tricks
['foo', 'jump']
b.tricks
[]          # Great, as expected
```

Now, the exact same setup, but executed in a different order: `add_trick` before direct setting of `trick`.

```
class Dog:

    tricks = []      

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks.append(trick)

    def print_self_tricks(self):
        print(self.tricks)

a = Dog('spencer')
b = Dog('rex')

a.add_trick('jump')

a.print_self_tricks()
['jump']
b.print_self_tricks() 
['jump']    # Welp, that's not expected. 
a.tricks
['jump']
b.tricks
['jump']    # Welp, that's not expected. 

a.tricks = ['foo']

a.print_self_tricks()
['foo']
b.print_self_tricks() 
['jump']    # Great, but inconsistent with the behavior above resulting from a.add_trick
a.tricks
['foo']
b.tricks
['jump']    # Great, but inconsistent with the behavior above resulting from a.add_trick
```

- Why does self.tricks exist? It was never defined in `__init__` (e.g.
  self.tricks = tricks). I wouldn't expect it to be possible to set
  self.tricks since it wasn't previously defined.
- Why does my approach not result in a different answer? That is, why does `a.tricks = ['foo']` seem to behave as intended compared `a.add_trick('roll over')`?
- It seems like order of operations matters. Why does calling `add_trick` before setting a.trick result in a different outcome?

*Here's what I've read so far, are there better explanations?

- [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)
- http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html
- https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/
- [https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-**init**-method-in-python-class/](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/)

Comment: "How is this even possible? Where did I define self.tricks?" - right there, on that line, with that assignment.

Comment: `# How is this even possible? Where did I define self.tricks?` Literally on that line. But you are getting confused because you are shadowing a class-level variable with an instance variable.

Comment: `tricks` in this case is a class variable shared across all instances of `Dog`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Dog:
    tricks = []
```

This defines `tricks` as a property on the *class*, not on any *instance*. A class property is in a sense "shared" between all instances of the class. It should ideally be accessed via the class: `Dog.tricks`, but Python also allows access via an instance, e.g. `a.tricks` or `self.tricks`. The rule is that if `x` is an instance, `x.y` will refer to the attribute `y` of the instance `x` if it exists, otherwise the attribute `y` of `x`'s class.

```
a.tricks = ['foo']
```

Python is a dynamically-typed language which does not require advance declarations of classes, attributes, or variables. This statement *creates* an attribute on the `Dog` instance that `a` refers to, and makes it refer to a list with one string. Before this, `a.tricks` would resolve to the still-empty list that the class attribute refers to, but after this, `a.tricks` will resolve to `['foo']`. `tricks` has not been set on `b`, so `b.tricks` still resolves to the same thing as `Dog.tricks`.

So the behavior you're seeing is because until you explicitly set `a.tricks` to something, `a` and `b` are *sharing* the class attribute. You probably didn't intend this - try the below, which will give each instance its own `tricks`:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = []
```